# FXML Set ButtonType onAction

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm building a DialogPane in FXML and I'm trying to figure out how to respond to button presses on the dialog since onAction is not a valid parameter for ButtonType. I've attached my FXML and Controller Class. There is very little documentation about DialogPane and even less about doing it in FXML so I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<DialogPane fx:id="loginPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="LoginController">
    <content>
        <GridPane hgap="5.0" vgap="5.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Label text="Driver Name" />
                <TextField fx:id="driverTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                <Label text="URL" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <TextField fx:id="urlTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Label text="Username" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <TextField fx:id="userTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Label text="Password" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                <TextField fx:id="passTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </content>
    <buttonTypes>
        <ButtonType fx:id="loginButton" text="Login" />
        <ButtonType fx:id="cancelBtn" text="Cancel" />
    </buttonTypes>
</DialogPane>

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    DialogPane loginPane;
    @FXML
    TextField driverTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField urlTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField userTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField passTxt;
    @FXML
    ButtonType loginButton;

    @FXML
    private void loginButtonAction(){
        // How do I do something here
    }

    public void initialize() {
        driverTxt.setText("org.postgresql.Driver");
        urlTxt.setText("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres");
        userTxt.setText("postgres");
        passTxt.setText("postgres");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't need to do this. You would usually show a `DialogPane` in a [`Dialog<ButtonType>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) calling its `showAndWait()` method, which returns an `Optional<ButtonType>` representing the button pressed (if any). So normal usage would be something like

```
public class LoginController {

    public static final ButtonType LOGIN = new ButtonType("Login");

    @FXML
    DialogPane loginPane;
    @FXML
    TextField driverTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField urlTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField userTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField passTxt;


    public void initialize() {
        driverTxt.setText("org.postgresql.Driver");
        urlTxt.setText("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres");
        userTxt.setText("postgres");
        passTxt.setText("postgres");
    }

    public String getDriver() {
        return driverTxt.getText();
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return urlTxt.getText();
    }

    public String getUser() {
        return userTxt.getText();
    }

    public String getPass() {
        return pass.getText();
    }

}
```

and make the following changes to your FXML file:

```xml
<buttonTypes>
    <LoginController fx:constant="LOGIN" />
    <ButtonType fx:constant="CANCEL" />
</buttonTypes>
```

Then you would use this with:

```
Dialog<ButtonType> dialog = new Dialog<>();
FXMLLoader dialogLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
dialog.setDialogPane(dialogLoader.load());
LoginController controller = dialogLoader.getController();
dialog.showAndWait().filter(LoginController.LOGIN::equals)
    .ifPresent(button -> {
        String driver = controller.getDriver();
        // etc etc
        // process login...
    });
```

As an alternative to exposing the text from the text fields, you could define a `processLogin()` method in the controller itself that read the text fields and did whatever you need to do:

```
public class LoginController {

    public static final ButtonType LOGIN = new ButtonType("Login");

    @FXML
    DialogPane loginPane;
    @FXML
    TextField driverTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField urlTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField userTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField passTxt;


    public void initialize() {
        driverTxt.setText("org.postgresql.Driver");
        urlTxt.setText("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres");
        userTxt.setText("postgres");
        passTxt.setText("postgres");
    }

    public void processLogin() {
        String driver = driverTxt.getText();
        // etc...
        // process login...
    }
}
```

then just do

```
// ...
dialog.showAndWait().filter(LoginController.LOGIN::equals)
    .ifPresent(button -> controller.processLogin());
```

If you really need to register an `onAction` handler with the login button, do it in the `initialize()` method in the controller:

```
public void initialize() {
    driverTxt.setText("org.postgresql.Driver");
    urlTxt.setText("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres");
    userTxt.setText("postgres");
    passTxt.setText("postgres");

    Button login = (Button) loginPane.lookupButton(loginButton);
    login.setOnAction(e -> { /* ... */ });
}
```

but this is really against the intended use of the dialog pane API.

---

One final alternative would be to override the `createButton` method in `DialogPane`. To do this, you'd need a subclass of `DialogPane`, which would mean using the [FXML custom component pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#custom_components).

So this would look something like:

```
public class LoginPane extends DialogPane {

    public static final ButtonType LOGIN = new ButtonType("Login");

    @FXML
    TextField driverTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField urlTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField userTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField passTxt;

    public LoginPane() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("LoginPane.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            // bad if you get here...
            throw new UncheckedIOException(exc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Node createButton(ButtonType buttonType) {
        Node button = super.createButton(buttonType);
        if (buttonType == LOGIN) {
            ((Button) button).setOnAction(e -> processLogin());
        }
        return button ;
    }


    public void initialize() {
        driverTxt.setText("org.postgresql.Driver");
        urlTxt.setText("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres");
        userTxt.setText("postgres");
        passTxt.setText("postgres");
    }

    public void processLogin() {
        String driver = driverTxt.getText();
        // etc...
        // process login...
    }
}
```

and the FXML would then look like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DialogPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<fx:root type="DialogPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <content>
        <GridPane hgap="5.0" vgap="5.0">
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="100.0" prefWidth="300.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
            <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            </rowConstraints>
            <children>
                <Label text="Driver Name" />
                <TextField fx:id="driverTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                <Label text="URL" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <TextField fx:id="urlTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                <Label text="Username" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <TextField fx:id="userTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                <Label text="Password" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                <TextField fx:id="passTxt" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            </children>
        </GridPane>
    </content>
    <buttonTypes>
        <LoginPane fx:constant="LOGIN" />
        <ButtonType fx:constant="CANCEL" />
    </buttonTypes>
</fx:root>
```

You would use this version with

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
dialog.setDialogPane(new LoginPane());
dialog.showAndWait();
```

so if you are looking to encapsulate as much as possible into the login pane and fxml, this is probably the cleanest option.

Note that the usage of `DialogPane` is fairly completely documented in the API docs for [`Dialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) and [`DialogPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html).

Comment: As a final note I updated my FXML to wrap DialogPane in a Dialog and then I was able to just use the FXMLLoader to create an instance of the Dialog from the FMXL and showAndWait using your example. Hardest part was that all of the examples I was finding weren't using FXML as their base and I'm trying to do as much there as possible.